# Missing parenthesis in query built by SolrNet

Tags: solr, solrnet

I'm building a Solr query with SolrNet and found that the resulting query is missing parenthesis in order for it to return my expected result. I wonder if I'm doing something wrong here, or if this is perhaps an issue in SolrNet or Solr. The fishy part of my SolrNet query in C# looks like this:

```
...
var filters = new List<ISolrQuery>();
filters.Add(new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(new ISolrQuery[] {
  new SolrNotQuery (new SolrQueryByField("ispage_b", "true")), // This line!
  new SolrQueryInList ("myfield_sm", arrayOfStringValues)
}, SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery.Operator.OR));
var options = new QueryOptions() { FilterQueries = filters };
...
```

The resulting query of this sent to Solr looks like this:

`?q=*:*&fq(-ispage_b:(true) OR (myfield_sm:((value1) OR (value2) OR (value3)))&...`

This doesn't give me my expected result. I'm not entirely sure why other than something going on with the priority of the minus `-` sign. I want all documents where either one of the values matches in `myfield_sm` OR the `ispage_b` isn't set to true (i.e. false or not present at all in the document.

From a Solr query perspective, this query works if I just add a set of parenthesis around the `-ispage_b` query, like this:

```
?q=*:*&fq((-ispage_b:(true)) OR (myfield_sm:((value1) OR (value2) OR (value3)))
          ^                ^
```

So translating this into a SolrNet query, I craft the query manually like this and it works:

```
new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(new ISolrQuery[] {
  new SolrQuery ("(-ispage_b:(true))"),  // raw query instead
  new SolrQueryInList ("myfield_sm", arrayOfStringValues)
}, SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery.Operator.OR)
```

I guess I'm missing something here. Am I doing something wrong in the initial query, or should SolrNet add a second set of parenthesis in `SolrNotQuery` or something else going on here?

Comment: Try adding a query for `*:*` before any of the other cvriterias in your multiplecriteriaquery - since Solr needs something to explicitly subtract the other documents from - and won't add `*:*` in front of complex queries where it can't be sure of the effect.

Comment: I already have `*:*` / `SolrQuery.All` in the query. I just omitted it from the sample code.

Comment: Yes, but the _filter query_ doesn't? The filter query works by intersecting the resulting set with the original set - if the filter query ends up as an empty set (because of the negative match having nothing to subtract from), nothing will be returned.